# Measure the time Firefox needs for rendering a page and evaluating JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, dom, firefox-addon

Is it possible to measure the time Firefox needs for rendering a page and evaluating all the JavaScript and CSS sources? I tried it with Firebug, YSlow and Google Page Speed but none of them satisfied my specific needs.

I need this for profiling a customer's web pages. But I have no idea how to do this.
It seems to be possible in Chrome ("Timeline" tab in developer tools"). But I guess Chrome (I have version 10) should be much faster than Firefox 3.6. so it's no valid reference system for my measurements.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What's wrong with the **Net** tab in Firebug?

Comment: I just don't know how I can read there what I need to know. Can you explain to me?

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

Comment: 'DOMContentLoaded' (event) - Point in time when DOMContentLoaded event was fired (since the beginning of the request, can be negative if the request has been started after the event)
'load' (event) - Point in time when the page load event was fired (since the beginning of the request, can be negative if the request has been started after the event)
Where can I read the values I need (e.g. time spent for loading?)

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is represented by the vertical blue line and `load` is represented by the vertical red line. You can see the exact values in milliseconds by hovering over the first request.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is as good as you are going to get, you could try this:

http://www.webpagetest.org/

I heard about it [on a Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_-YukDEDBE&feature=channel_video_title) with a guy from Edmunds - very good

Comment: Thanks Myles, but I need something to test offline-pages

Comment: @Benjamin If you are testing OFFLINE pages your results will be severely skewed as you will be pulling from the HDD and you wont have to worry about things like access times and HTTPReqs etc?

Comment: @Myles: Okay maybe "offline" was the wrong word. It is hosted in a intranet.

Comment: @Benjamin still your access times will be nothing due to the latency over a LAN based against latency and ping times over a WAN, you could set up a `no-index` domain to test from?

Comment: @Myles: But that's nothing I want to measure. I want to know the time my browser needs to build the DOM, parse CSS and evaluating JavaScript.

Comment: @Benjamin well the Net tab if Firebug is more than enough in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I use dynaTrace AJAX Edition. It works with Firefox and IE. It is an advanced profiling tool. http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/

Answer (score -1):

You need `FireBug`! 
https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Maybe you can explain to me how I can use it for my needs?

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel Here's the tutorial on the NET-panel, wich will show you how long it took to render the page including al requests..

Comment: The Net panel shows how long it takes to download the file, but not how long the browser takes to parse that file.